# Arrayfire: How do I sample an array by elements of another array?

Tags: arrayfire

I'm new to Arrayfire and searching for a method like 2D texture sampling.

```
float uvInit[] = { 0, 0,  1, 1,  1, 0,  0, 1 };
array uv = array(4, 2, uvInit, f32);

float texInit[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
array tex = array(2, 2, texInit, f32);

array color = ???????;
// color should be 1d array { 1, 4, 3, 2 },
// e.g. { tex(0, 0), tex(1, 1), tex(1, 0), tex(0, 1) }.
```

Searched for documentation but not found anything like this, and I cannot even index an array with array element...

```
array s = ..., g = ...;
gfor(seq i, ...) {
    auto x = g(0, i);    // take an element from g.
    s(x);                // ERROR: no matched function.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest sibling for interpolation in ArrayFire are the functions listed in the below page.

http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__approx__mat.htm

If you are new to ArrayFire/indexing, I strongly recommend you to go through the documentation tutorials.

http://arrayfire.org/docs/indexing.htm

The whole list of tutorials(may not be comprehensive, but a very good starter) is given at the following URL.

http://arrayfire.org/docs/usergroup0.htm

Comment: Oops, just didn't get it is interpolation operation.